# Buying Bitcoin Cash

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

Hopefully my question is relevant based on my understanding I received during the tour. I would like to buy Bitcoin cash. I have GDAX/Blockchain account but Bitcoin cash is not available to buy on those sites. Can you advice? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can buy BCH on other sites, such as https://www.kraken.com.

I hope it helps,

David

Answer (score 1):

There are many altcoin exchanges such as Bitfinex that you can buy the altcoin bitcoin cash, but you should be warey that the price is being heavily manipulated by the project owners